Crash When Promoting QWidget to Custom Widget Derived from QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget from DLL in Qt Application
I've encountered a consistent crash in my Qt application when promoting a QWidget to a custom widget class derived from QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget, which is encapsulated within a dynamically linked library (DLL). The issue specifically arises when I use the Qt Designer promotion feature to substitute a standard QWidget with my custom Graph_widget class. However, directly creating and displaying Graph_widget in the main function does not lead to any crashes.
Environment:
Operating System: Windows 10 |
IDE: Visual Studio 2022 |
Qt Version: 6.6.3 |
VTK Version: 9.2.2
Observation:
Using Qt Designer to promote a QWidget to Graph_widget results in an application crash on startup. Direct instantiation of Graph_widget in the application's main function operates without any issues.
The stack trace looks like pointing to failures within VTK’s OpenGL handling routines:
test.exe!vtkOpenGLState::vtkBindFramebuffer(unsigned int,class vtkOpenGLFramebufferObject *)
test.exe!vtkOpenGLFramebufferObject::Bind(unsigned int)
test.exe!vtkOpenGLRenderWindow::BlitDisplayFramebuffer(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int) 
test.exe!QVTKRenderWindowAdapter::QVTKInternals::blit(unsigned int,int,class QRect const &,bool)    
test.exe!QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget::paintGL(void)

DLL Details:
The Graph_widget class is compiled into a DLL using MSVC, DLLs and the main application use the same compiler and link options.
The following are Code snippets of a MWE:
Qt application named test and DLL with Graph_widget exported:
main.cpp:
#include "test.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <tv/graph_widget.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // the following line has no effect
  QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget::defaultFormat());

  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  // Crash on starting up
  Test w;
  w.show();

  // Works fine if uncommenting the following, and commenting the above
  //Graph_widget gw;
  //gw.show();

  return a.exec();
}

test.h
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_test.h"

class Test : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Test(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Test();

    Ui::TestClass ui;
};

test.cpp
#include "test.h"

Test::Test(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

Test::~Test()
{}

test.ui:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>TestClass</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="TestClass">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>906</width>
    <height>500</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Test</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="Graph_widget" name="widget" native="true"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>906</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>Graph_widget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>tv/graph_widget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>

DLL:
graph_widget.h
#ifndef GRAPH_WIDGET_H
#define GRAPH_WIDGET_H

#include <QResizeEvent>

#include <QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget.h>

#if defined(SHARED_LIBRARY)
#define LIBRARY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBRARY_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class LIBRARY_EXPORT Graph_widget : public QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Graph_widget(QWidget* parent = NULL,
    Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());

protected:
  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;
};

#endif // GRAPH_WIDGET_H

widget_graph.cpp:
#include "graph_widget.h"

#include <vtkNamedColors.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow.h>
#include <QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget.h>
#include <QOpenGLContext>

Graph_widget::Graph_widget(QWidget* parent,
  Qt::WindowFlags f)
  : QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget(parent, f)
{ 
  vtkNew<vtkNamedColors> colors;
  vtkNew<vtkSphereSource> shereSource;

  vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> shereMapper;
  shereMapper->SetInputConnection(shereSource->GetOutputPort());
  vtkNew<vtkActor> shereActor;
  shereActor->SetMapper(shereMapper);
  shereActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(colors->GetColor4d("Tomato").GetData());
  vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;
  renderer->AddActor(shereActor);
  renderer->SetBackground(colors->GetColor3d("SteelBlue").GetData());

  vtkRenderWindow* renderwindow = renderWindow();
  renderwindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
  renderwindow->SetWindowName("RenderWindowNoUIFile");

  renderwindow->Render();
}

void Graph_widget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
  QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget::resizeEvent(event);
}

I'm seeking insights on why this crash occurs when using Qt Designer's promotion feature but not when the widget is used directly in the main function, and how this issue can be resolved.
Any help will be grateful!
